# C# DataGridView: Value disappearing in dynamic added column

Tags: c#, datagridviewcolumn

I am coming across something strange or maybe it is the way it works and its just my lack of understand of how the datagridview works. I am dynamically adding a column when I click on a button

```
    private void btnAssign_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!gvData.Columns.Contains("DepartmentId"))
        {
            DataGridViewTextBoxCell cell = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
            DataGridViewColumn dc = new DataGridViewColumn();
            dc = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            dc.HeaderText = "DepartmentId";
            dc.Name = "DepartmentId";
            dc.CellTemplate = cell;
            gvData.Columns.Add(dc);
        }
        foreach(DataGridViewRow row in gvData.SelectedRows)
        {
            row.Cells["DepartmentId"].Value = getSelectedValues(clbDept);
        }
    }
```

first it checks if the DepartmentId column is in the datagridview (dgv). If not then I create a new Datagridviewtextboxcolumn and sets the appropriate settings. Then adds values to the cells. SO far so good... this where is does weird things... when I sort another column, the data in the 'DepartmentId' column disappears. Data disappears in the columns that I dynamically create. Do i have to use a save method or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding data directly to datagridview you need to add column to datasource and reassign the datasource to datagridview. This will resolve your sorting issue.